# Content overflowing from flex column in tailwind

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend, overflow, tailwind-css

[image]

In my footer design, the content of the first column in flex is overflowing its parent. How to confine this in its parent column? Although I've used the same classes for this as in other columns and they are well inside their parent column, this column is behaving a bit weirdly.
My HTML looks as following:

```
<footer class="bg-Space-Cadet p-5 px-48 pt-16 relative overflow-hidden z-0">
  <%= image_tag "logo-lg-gray.svg", class: "absolute top-0 right-[1rem] z-10", alt: "stripe logo" %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="text-xs text-White opacity-50 font-medium mb-4">Aid Humanity is a UK registered charity 1184639.</p>
    <div class="flex gap-12">
      <!-- First col  -->
      <div class="flex flex-col basis-[40%] border-2 border-White">
        <div class="mr-12 ">
          <div class="flex">
            <%= image_tag "footer-logo.png", class: "h-[7.4rem] w-[10.6rem]", alt: "footer logo" %>
            <div class="ml-12 flex flex-col justify-between">
              <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center">
                <%= image_tag "phone.png", class: "w-[17px] h-[1rem] mr-1", alt: "phone icon" %>
                <div><p class="text-Vivd-Cerulean text-lg font-bold tracking-[-.27px]">0330 057 9957</p></div>
              </div>
              <div><p class="text-Amber text-lg font-semibold tracking-[-.27px]">info@aidhumanity.co.uk</p></div>
              <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-[10.3rem]">
                <%= image_tag "facebook.png", class: "w-[9px] h-[1rem]", alt: "facebook icon" %>
                <%= image_tag "twitter.png", class: "w-[20px] h-[17px]", alt: "twitter icon" %>
                <%= image_tag "instagram.png", class: "w-[25px] h-[25px]", alt: "instagram icon" %>
                <%= image_tag "linkedin.png", class: "w-[18px] h-[17px]", alt: "linkedin icon" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="text-Bluish text-base font-medium leading-[26px] tracking-[-.24px] mt-6">Aid Humanity is proud to be a non-profit organization that passes 100% of our donations to charitable causes around the world.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center mt-[4rem]">
          <span class="text-xs text-White opacity-50 font-medium mr-2">Registered with</span>
          <%= image_tag "regulator.png", class: "w-[7.5rem] h-[2.25rem] mix-blend-luminosity", alt: "regulator icon" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Second column -->
      <div class="flex flex-col basis-[20%] border-solid border-orange-900 ">
        <span class="text-White mb-3 font-semibold text-sm tracking-[-.21px]">ABOUT US</span>
        <ul class="text-Bluish flex flex-col text-base font-medium leading-[30px] tracking-[-.24px]">
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Our Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Zakat</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Get Involved</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">How it works</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Become a Fundraiser</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Third column -->
      <div class="flex flex-col basis-[20%] border-solid  border-orange-900 ">
        <span class="text-White mb-3 text-link-heading-color font-semibold text-sm tracking-[-.21px]">APPEALS</span>
        <ul class="text-Bluish flex flex-col text-base font-medium leading-[30px] tracking-[-.24px]">
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Build a Mosque</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Disaster & Emergency</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Appeals</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Water For All</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Sponsor an Orphan</a></li>
          <li><a href="/" class="hover:underline">Hunger Appeal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Fourth colmn -->
      <div class="flex flex-col  border-2 border-White">
        <span class="text-White mb-3 text-link-heading-color font-semibold text-sm tracking-[-.21px]">NEWSLETTER</span>
        <span class="text-White font-bold text-lg leading-7 tracking-[-.45px]">Subscribe to the free newsletter and stay up-to date</span>
        <div class="flex mt-5 mr-0">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center w-full">
              <input type="search" class="form-control relative min-w-0 w-[16.8rem] h-[2.5rem] block px-3 py-0 text-base font-normal text-secondary-light bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded-lg" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
              <button class="w-[45px] h-[40px] ml-3 bg-Vivd-Cerulean text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 flex items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="45" height="10.121" viewBox="0 0 13.24 10.121">
                  <g id="arrow-right" transform="translate(0.75 1.061)">
                    <path id="Path_4820" data-name="Path 4820" d="M6.962.7l3.911,3.97L6.962,8.7" transform="translate(0.865 -0.702)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" />
                    <line id="Line_158" data-name="Line 158" x1="11.74" transform="translate(0 4)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1.5" />
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center text-White mt-[6.8rem]">
          <span class="font-semibold text-lg tracking-[-.9px] mr-4">we transfer</span>
          <%= image_tag "100percent.png", class: "w-[113px] h-[46px]", alt: "100percent" %>
          <span class="font-semibold text-xs tracking-[-.6px] ml-1">of your donation</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="flex justify-center space-x-6 text-White opacity-50 mt-[50px] text-xs font-normal tracking-[-.06px]">
      <li><a href="/" class="">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="">Donation Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="">Refund Policy</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr class="my-3 bg-White opacity-25 h-[0.15rem]">

    <div class="flex justify-between items-center mt-4">
      <p class="opacity-50 text-xs tracking-[-.06px]">
        <span class="font-medium">&copy; 2022</span>
        <span class="font-semibold">Aid Humanity.</span>
        <span class="font-medium">All rights reserved.</span>
      </p>
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center basis-[25%]">
        <%= image_tag "visa.png", class: "w-[43px] h-[14px] mix-blend-luminosity", alt: "visa logo" %>
        <%= image_tag "mastercard.png", class: "w-[29px] h-[18px] mix-blend-luminosity", alt: "mastercard logo" %>
        <%= image_tag "paypal.png", class: "w-[87px] h-[21px] mix-blend-luminosity", alt: "paypal logo" %>
        <%= image_tag "stripe.png", class: "w-[53px] h-[22px] mix-blend-luminosity", alt: "stripe logo" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```